Remove repeat tests within 6 weeks using data.table
I have a data set with individuals taking an STI test at different clinics. I want to allow each person to only have one test every 6 weeks in the final data set.
There are similar questions relating to this
as seen here. However, I tried using this code and it takes so long to run as my data set has over 40 million rows. Therefore, I would like to use data.table as this is often faster.
Please see a data set which can be used:
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

date=c("2023-01-01", "2023-02-07", "2023-02-20", "2023-01-01", "2023-05-10", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10", "2023-04-10", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10")
ID=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E")
clinic=c("clinic1", "clinic1", "clinic1", "clinic2", "clinic2", "clinic3", "clinic4", "clinic5", "clinic4", "clinic6", "clinic6")
df=as.data.frame(cbind(date, ID, clinic))

df=df %>% mutate(date=as.Date(date))
df=data.table(df)

In this example, I would want person A's test on the 7th Feb and person E's test on the 10th Jan to be removed.

And presumably person D's test on the 10th Jan as well?

This can be done with a reduction (base::Reduce or purrr::reduce):
df[, date := as.Date(date)] # since you have strings
df[, .SD[Reduce(function(kept, rn) c(kept, if (diff(date[c(kept[length(kept)], rn)]) >= 6*7) rn),
                seq_len(.N)[-1], init=1),], ID]
#        ID       date  clinic
#    <char>     <Date>  <char>
# 1:      A 2023-01-01 clinic1
# 2:      A 2023-02-20 clinic1
# 3:      B 2023-01-01 clinic2
# 4:      B 2023-05-10 clinic2
# 5:      C 2023-01-01 clinic3
# 6:      D 2023-01-01 clinic4
# 7:      D 2023-04-10 clinic4
# 8:      E 2023-01-01 clinic6

The anon-function is given two arguments:

kept is the previously "accepted" positions (row indices) to be kept, initialized to be just "1";
for each row 2:.N (within a group), we determine if the last date indexed by kept is within 6*7 days of this date, ala date[ kept[length(kept)] ] is within 42 days of date[ rn ]; if that is true, then we append rn to the previous vector in kept

